# Dont show empty line when EL is empty

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

In a jsp page I have a text area where the user can enter an address on three line, each line are saved in tree different variable (database restriction). Everything work well when I save the value from the user to my DTO, but when I show them back in the edit form I get empty line where I don't want them

The jsp code:

```
   <textarea id="address-lines" name="address-lines" rows="3">
${address.line1}
${address.line2}
${address.line3}
    </textarea>
```

If only the address.line1 has value I get:

```
---
line 1 value


---
```

I'd like to get only

```
---
line 1 value
---
```

Is this possible with the jstl? Should I create my own tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a text area, it renders newlines.

Construct the value in the Java layer and use only a single value in the text area, e.g.,

**Java pseudocode**

```
fullAddress = Strings.join("\n", address.line1, address.line2, address.line3);
```

**JSP**

```
<textarea id="address-lines" name="address-lines" rows="3">${fullAddress}</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't have much control on the class given to the jsp and the address class is contain in a list much of the time so I can't just add a new attribute from the jsp controller, but I agree that would probably be the best

Comment: @JonatanCloutier You can still create a new variable in the same way and expose it to the page, though.

Comment: Well, there is many other member that I use on the address class (city, country) I'd need to rebuild the whole data in another list. I think I'll go with a custom tag or ELfunction for that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I like Dave's answer, but if you have no control over the Java source code, you could do this all using JSTL and the html entity for the newline character.

```
<c:if test="${not empty address.line1}">${address.line1}&#10;</c:if><c:if test="${not empty address.line2}">${address.line2}&#10;</c:if><c:if test="${not empty address.line3}">${address.line3}&#10;</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the html entity in this case. I will look at that but it should work in my case. And I agree with you that Dave way is better in most case.